# Why are some of my assumptions ignored?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, calculus-and-analysis

In my opinion *Mathematica* should be able to further calculate and simplify the output of `G1[...]`.

```
g[z_, A_, e_, b_] := 
 Assuming[A > b/2 && z \[Element] Reals && A \[Element] Reals && 
   b > 0 && e >= 0 && b \[Element] Reals && e \[Element] Reals && 
   z > A - b/2 + e && z < A + b/2 + e, 
  PDF[UniformDistribution[{A + e - b/2, A + e + b/2}], z]]
G[z_, A_, e_, b_] := 
 Assuming[A > b/2 && z \[Element] Reals && A \[Element] Reals && 
   b > 0 && e >= 0 && b \[Element] Reals && e \[Element] Reals && 
   z > A - b/2 + e && z < A + b/2 + e, 
  CDF[UniformDistribution[{A + e - b/2, A + e + b/2}], z]]

  H10[A_, b_, y_, s_] := 
     Assuming[A > b/2 && y ∈ Reals && A ∈ Reals && 
        b > 0 && b ∈ Reals && y < A + 1 + b/2 && 
        y > A - b/2 + 1 && s > A - b/2 && s < A + b/2,
       G[s, A, 0, b]/G[y, A, 1, b]] // FullSimplify

  H11[A_, b_, y_, s_] := 
     Assuming[A > b/2 && y ∈ Reals && A ∈ Reals && 
        b > 0 && b ∈ Reals && y > A + 1 - b/2 && 
        y < A + 1 + b/2 && s > A + 1 - b/2 && s < A + 1 + b/2,
       G[s, A, 1, b]/G[y, A, 1, b]] // FullSimplify

  G1[A_, b_, y_, p0h_, p0l_, c1_] = 
     Assuming[A > b/2 && y ∈ Reals && A ∈ Reals && 
        b > 0 && f ∈ Reals && e ∈ Reals && 
        b ∈ Reals && y > A + 1 - b/2 && y < A + 1 + b/2, 
       Integrate[g[y, A, 1, b]*1/2 (
           p0h*
             Integrate[H10[A, b, y, s], {s, A + 0 - b/2, y}] + (1 - p0h)*
             Integrate[H11[A, b, y, s], {s, A + 1 - b/2, y}] +
            p0l*
             Integrate[H10[A, b, y, s], {s, A + 0 - b/2, y}] + (1 - p0l)*
             Integrate[H11[A, b, y, s], {s, A + 1 - b/2, y}]), {y, 
          A + 1 - b/2, A + 1 + b/2}] - c1] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

I think I clearly told *Mathematica* in `G1[...]` that `A<b/2 && b>0`, but somehow it did not use it in `FullSimplify`.

In my opinion *Mathematica* should give me a closed form expression without any cases inside.

Did I misuse `Assuming` or am I missing something else?

Comment: Take a look at what you are trying to simplify: G[s, A, 0, b]/G[y, A, 1, b]. This term is a ratio of two piecewise functions, one is a function of s and one a function of y. What possible simplification is there?

Comment: Note that `Assuming[a, e]` affects only the evaluation of `e` if `e` contains a function that applies `$Assumptions`.  However, `H10`,  `H11`, and `G1` are of the form `Assuming[a, e] // FullSimplify`, so the assumptions `a` will not be applied by `FullSimplify`; the assumptions in `H10` and `H11` will be applied in `G1` by `Integrate` and `FullSimplify` (although the assumptions in `G1` will be applied by `Integrate` only. It's not clear just from reading the question if this is what you want or not -- that is, which assumptions you think are being ignored. `PiecewiseExpand` might help.

Comment: @bills The first piecewise function should reduce to simply `1/b`. `PiecewiseExpand` will do this, if given the appropriate assumptions.

Comment: Thx, Michael. I updated my question and I hope it is more clear, now.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It always help us to help you when you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit] if improvable, show due diligence, pay attention to the comments, you still have `FullSimplify` outside `Assuming`! Doesn't that solves your problem?  As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned. Why not choosing a meaningful username?

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, mistaking the order in which you apply functions) and is unlikely to help any future visitors as it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @Michael E2, you must use `Assuming[a, FullSimplify[b]]` and not `FullSimplify[Assuming[a, b]]` if you want [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) to use the assumptions.

```
g[z_, A_, e_, b_] := 
 PDF[UniformDistribution[{A + e - b/2, A + e + b/2}], z];
G[z_, A_, e_, b_] := 
 CDF[UniformDistribution[{A + e - b/2, A + e + b/2}], z];

H10[A_, b_, y_, s_] := Assuming[
  A > b/2 && y ∈ Reals && A ∈ Reals && b > 0 && b ∈ Reals && y < A + 1 + b/2 && y > A - b/2 + 1 && s > A - b/2 && s < A + b/2,
  FullSimplify[G[s, A, 0, b]/G[y, A, 1, b]]
  ]

H11[A_, b_, y_, s_] := Assuming[
 A > b/2 && y ∈ Reals && A ∈ Reals && b > 0 && b ∈ Reals && y > A + 1 - b/2 && y < A + 1 + b/2 && s > A + 1 - b/2 && s < A + 1 + b/2,
  FullSimplify[
   G[s, A, 1, b]/G[y, A, 1, b]]
  ]

Assuming[A > b/2 && y ∈ Reals && A ∈ Reals && b > 0 && f ∈ Reals && e ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals && y > A + 1 - b/2 && y < A + 1 + b/2,
  FullSimplify[
   Integrate[
     g[y, A, 1, b]*1/
       2 (p0h*
         Integrate[H10[A, b, y, s], {s, A + 0 - b/2, y}] + (1 - p0h)*
         Integrate[H11[A, b, y, s], {s, A + 1 - b/2, y}] + 
        p0l*Integrate[
          H10[A, b, y, s], {s, A + 0 - b/2, y}] + (1 - p0l)*
         Integrate[H11[A, b, y, s], {s, A + 1 - b/2, y}]), {y, 
      A + 1 - b/2, A + 1 + b/2}] - c1]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]